# cron: 5/15 * * * * doesn't work (run every 15 minutes starting from 5 minutes past the hour)

Tags: cron

`*/15 * * * *` works fine by running every 15 minutes starting from the top of the hour.

I need a task to run every 15 minutes starting from 5 minutes past the hour. Several cron simulators, eg [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#5/15_*_*_*_*), say it should be `5/15 * * * *`, but when I use that, nothing runs.

What should be the proper syntax?

Comment: crontab: 5,20,35,50 * * * *

Comment: Just to point out, you said that "Several cron simulators say it should be X but when I use that, nothing runs" with a link to crontab.guru. **But, on that link, there's a message written below:** "Non standard! May not work with every cron.". If you use one of the two working answers, this message goes away.

Comment: for future reference: https://crontab.guru/ :)

Comment: @Rinzwind, that's exactly the site they link to in their question, and exactly the site that gives the interpretation that's not valid for vixie-cron

Comment: `5-50/15 * * * *` will be more clear and neat.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will cause your script to run every 15 minutes starting at 5 minutes past the hour.  Hope this helps.

crontab: `5,20,35,50 * * * *`

Answer (score 16):

Either try @jones0610's suggestion, or this one:

```
5-59/15 * * * * command
```

I think 5/15 will run only once per hour, at 5 minutes past the hour.

Answer (score 11):

The [man page crontab(5)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man5/crontab.5.html) from the package [`cron`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lunar/+package/cron) says:

> Step  values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with `/<number>`
> specifies skips of the number's value through the range.  For example, `0-23/2`  can  be
> used  in the hours field to specify command execution every other hour (the alternative in
> the V7 standard is `0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22`).  Steps are also permitted after an
> asterisk, so if you want to say "every two hours", just use `*/2`.

It doesn't say ranges could be used with single values, so indeed `5/15` doesn't appear valid. (Even if we took it to mean every fifteen minutes within the degenerate one-value range, it'd still be just the same as just `5` and using it would be silly.)

There may be other implementations, but I believe that's the one installed by default on Ubuntu. In any case, it often pays off to consult the documentation of the software you're using instead of random internet resources which may neglect to mention the scope their explanations are valid in.